# Redactor: dropdown plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker, redactor

I try to implement a colorpicker-fontcolor plugin to redactor-js.

http://jsfiddle.net/ped7txq6/

```
$(function(){

    //plugin
    $.Redactor.prototype.fontcolor = function()
    {
        return {
            init: function()
            {
                var name = 'fontcolor';
                var rdctr = this;

                var button = this.button.addAfter('fontsize', name, this.lang.get(name));
                var $dropdown = this.button.addDropdown(button);

                $dropdown.css('min-width', '199px');
                this.fontcolor.buildPicker($dropdown, name);

                button.on('click', function(){

                    rdctr.selection.save();

                });
            },
            buildPicker: function($dropdown, name)
            {
                var rdctr = this;

                var $picker = $('<p>').ColorPicker({
                                                    flat: true,
                                                    onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el){
                                                    //  $(el).val('#' + hex);
                                                    //  $(el).ColorPickerHide();
                                                    },
                                                    onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el){
                                                    //  $(el).val(hex);
                                                        rdctr.fontcolor.set('color', '#' + hex);
                                                    }
                                                }).bind('keyup', function(){
                                                    //$(rdctr).ColorPickerSetColor(rdctr.value);
                                                //  rdctr.fontcolor.set('color', '#' + hex);

                                                });
                $dropdown.append($picker);
            },
            set: function(rule, type)
            {
                console.log('_', type);
                //selected color
                this.selection.restore();
                this.inline.format('span', 'style', rule + ':' + type + ';');
            },
            remove: function(rule)
            {
                //removed color
            //  this.inline.removeStyleRule(rule);
            }
        };
    };

    //editor
    $('#redactor').redactor({

        plugins: ['fontcolor'],
        focus: true,
        changeCallback: function()
        {
        },
        blurCallback: function()
        {
        }

    });

});
```

I have two problem:

1. When I clicked in the dropdown on the colorpicker, the dropdown is close,
2. Sometimes when I selected the color, the text in the editor get the default color, not actual color from colorpicker.

Anyone can help in these?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Check the [font color plugin](http://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/font-color/) for Redactor